# how to set "ShibRequireSession" on or off for a URL in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shibboleth

I want some thing like this, when a user visits a url `www.example.com` no rules is applied on it but, when user visits `www.example.com/something else` rules should be like,

```
->http://www.example.com/something else
->http://www.example.com/something else1
->http://www.example.com/something else2
AuthType shibboleth
ShibRequireSession On
Require user
```

But at the same instance is user visits `www.example.com/someother thing` these rules should not be applied to the url.

I do not want to create another folder and write a .htaccess separately,

Is it possible, Please tell me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this,

```
AuthType shibboleth   
ShibRequireSession Off
require shibboleth
```

and, Call the links like `/Shibboleth.sso/Login?target=http://www.example.com/something else2`

And catch the enviorment variables with `HTTP_SHIB_... variable` and use shibboleth authentication